# Getting a NoSuchMethodError on a Xstream.addPermission()

Tags: java, xstream, nosuchmethoderror

I'm trying to debug a issue I'm having on an application, we have a function to store a user's search criteria and the function used to work but recently we've been getting a NoSuchMethod
Error whenever a user attempts to retrieve their saved search criteria. I've tried prowling through some other Xstream errors but the closest I found was an issue a couple of years back from the .alias method.
I'm getting the error when attempting to use the .addPermission() method. I've attached one of the other methods that we use to "getXstream".

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.addPermission(Lcom/thoughtworks/xstream/security/TypePermission;)V
    at com.u90785.aim.persistence.brokers.SavedSearchBroker.ParseXML(SavedSearchBroker.java:986)
    at com.u90785.aim.persistence.brokers.SavedSearchBroker.populateSearchCriteriaFromXML(SavedSearchBroker.java:840)
    at com.u90785.aim.persistence.brokers.SavedSearchBroker.RetrieveSavedSearchCriteria(SavedSearchBroker.java:384)
    at com.u90785.aim.persistence.brokers.SavedSearchBroker.RetrieveSavedSearchCriteria(SavedSearchBroker.java:330)
    at com.u90785.aim.domain.SavedSearchCriteria.GetSavedSearch(SavedSearchCriteria.java:56)
```

```
    protected static FindSearchCriteria ParseXML(String xml, XStream xstream, User user)
    {
        if (xml == null || xml.trim().length() == 0 || !xml.trim().startsWith("<")) return null;
        if (xstream == null) {
            xstream = GetXStream();
            xstream.addPermission(NoTypePermission.NONE);
            xstream.addPermission(NullPermission.NULL);
            xstream.addPermission(PrimitiveTypePermission.PRIMITIVES);
        }


    private static XStream GetXStream()
    {
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        //These converters used so that cached counties, states, and countries are used instead of 
        //creating new instances
        //If additional "cached" objects are added to the domain, converters should be created for 
        //them.
        xstream.registerConverter(new CountyConverter());
        xstream.registerConverter(new StateProvinceConverter());
        xstream.registerConverter(new CountryConverter());
        xstream.registerConverter(new DateConverter());
        xstream.registerConverter(new CategoryConverter());
        xstream.registerConverter(new SegmentConverter());
        xstream.registerConverter(new SubSegmentConverter());
        xstream.registerConverter(new AffiliationConverter());

        return xstream;
    }
```

I'm kind of stumped since this issue just cropped up relatively recently and we haven't touched this part of our application in a quite some time. From what I can tell we also haven't updated any of our dependencies recently either (Xstream is running 1.4.8 as far as I can tell). I've tried exploring the methods but I can't find anything that specifically sticks or is glaringly off. This application also predates my contributions so it's possible it's an unfamiliarity with parts of the code.

Comment: Are you sure you are using XStream 1.4.8 (or greater)? Have you recently upgraded? It looks like [the method `XStream.addPermission()` was added in 1.4.7](https://abi-laboratory.pro/?view=compat_report&lang=java&l=xstream&v1=1.4.6&v2=1.4.7&obj=d6107&kind=bin), so the error you are getting would be explained if your run time version of XStream was < 1.4.7. I'm not saying that is the case at all....just mentioning it as a possibility, since there has obviously been some change in your environment to provoke the error.

Comment: @skomisa Our Maven Dependencies says we have 1.4.8. I'm having trouble finding the change myself since even looking back through our commits we haven't even touched the file containing this method in a while. I know we've done work elsewhere to fix an issue with HTML encoding some strings (we were encoding strings to html and pushing to a csv which was causing the files to output weird) which cropped up but that should be unrelated here.

Comment: OK, since your code was built with 1.4.8 it's fine, and all I can think of is that something changed in the runtime environment. That might be the scenario in my previous comment (i.e. the rt version of XStream is < 1.4.7), or alternatively, having multiple instances of XStream available at runtime, which might perhaps cause class loader to trigger a `NoSuchMethodError` even if both/all the XStream instances were >= 1.4.7. Does this issue occur on every machine your app runs on? If not, the obvious thing to do is see what environment differences exist between the machines (classpath, etc.).

Comment: @skomisa This error exists on my local copy as well as the copy sitting on our "server". We get the same error when trying to retrieve the search criteria on all copies.

Comment: I'm baffled. If it's not a big deal, perhaps consider rebuilding and running your app locally using [the latest version of XStream which is 1.4.19](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream), since your version is quite old. But that's just to see if the problem mysteriously goes away, and I can't provide a persuasive reason for doing it - it's just something to try.

Comment: One final thought...have there been any changes to your Java runtime environment lately? Perhaps that `NoSuchMethodError` is misleading, and there is an underlying Java issue with something having been removed. Was your app built using JDK 8, but you are now running it using a JDK > 8? (Again, just wild speculation on my part.)

Comment: @skomisa No, we are using the same version of the Amazon Corretto JDK. We haven't changed much in terms of the runtime environment in a while. Looking back at previous builds this issue has been apparent for some iterations now (again no changes to the RTE just to various methods and files) just no one cared to raise a issue until a week ago.